# How to getString(Table.Column) in ResultSet JayBird

Tags: java, jdbc, firebird, resultset, jaybird

I need to use the database Firebird and for this I use the Jaybird 2.2.9.

When I used the MySQL driver, to converter of `ResultSet` to `Object` this way:

```
empresa.setBairro(rs.getString("empresa.bairro")); // (Table.Column)
empresa.setCep(rs.getString("empresa.cep")); // (Table.Column)
empresa.setCidade(rs.getString("empresa.cidade")); // (Table.Column)
```

But with Jaybird the `resultSet` don't return `rs.getString("Table.Column")`

I need this way when I have inner join in `SQL`.

Anyone help me?

This is my full code

```
public ContaLivros converterContaLivros(ResultSet rs, Integer linha) throws Exception {
    if (rs.first()) {

        rs.absolute(linha);

        ContaLivros obj = new ContaLivros();

        obj.setId(rs.getLong("cad_conta.auto_id"));
        obj.setNome(rs.getString("cad_conta.nome"));


        if (contain("cad_banco.auto_id", rs)) {

            obj.setBancoLivros(converterBancoLivros(rs, linha));
        } else {

            obj.setBancoLivros(new BancoLivros(rs.getLong("cad_conta.banco"), null, null, null));
        }
        obj.setAgencia(rs.getInt("cad_conta.agencia"));
        obj.setAgenciaDigito(rs.getInt("cad_conta.agencia_digito"));
        obj.setConta(rs.getInt("cad_conta.conta"));
        obj.setContaDigito(rs.getInt("cad_conta.conta_digito"));
        obj.setLimite(rs.getDouble("cad_conta.limite"));
        obj.setAtivo(rs.getString("cad_conta.ativo"));

        return obj;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have code for resultset to object mapper? You will not have two object fields with same name as well?

Comment: If I use rs.getString("Table.Column") as mysql driver, I never have two object fields with same name.

Comment: And how did you map table1.col and table2.col into the object? If you showed part of your code we could think of a better way. By the way: most object-relatuonal mappers i know do it witj aliases

Comment: a put my full converter above.

Comment: If you have no **duplicate** column names you can simply do rs.getInt("agencia")); and so on?!

Comment: I have the column auto_id duplicate in table cad_conta and cad_banco

Comment: The way the MySQL driver allows you to request a column with `<table>.<column>` is non-standard (it is not specified in the JDBC specification). The JDBC specification also specifies that if there are multiple columns with the same name, then it should return the first column with that name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Jaybird retrieves the columns by its label as specified in JDBC 4.2, section 15.2.3. In Firebird the column label is either the original column name, or the AS alias, the table name isn't part of this. The extension of MySQL that you can prefix the table name for disambiguation is non-standard.

Your options are to specify aliases in the query and retrieve by this aliasname, or to process the result set metadata to find the right indexes for each column and retrieve by index instead.

However note that in certain queries (for example `UNION`), the `ResultSetMetaData.getTableName` cannot return the table name, as Firebird doesn't "know" it (as you could be applying a UNION to selects from different tables).

Comment: I understood, but this solution facilitated my live with mysql driver. With JayBird I will use alias in my sql. If you can implement this solution in JayBird I think that help many programmers as I.

Tanks @Mark Rotteveel

Comment: @TiagoRoquedeCarvalho If you create an improvement request in the tracker at http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/JDBC then I will consider it (no promises though, there is more to do and my time is limited, and I am not sure I like the idea of adding non-standard features).

Comment: I will create an improvement request, Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The name in jdbc will not have the table in it.

You can either

- work with positional parameters ( `getString (1);` and so on )

Or

- define column name alias in your select (`select a.name namefroma from tableone a` )

Or

- simply do rs.getString  ("column"); without the table prefix if name is unambigous

Comment: I used your second suggestion. But I think this way is very work, all sql I need to use alias, because I have one converter for table to object. Don't have another way as mysql driver?

Comment: If your tables have lots of column names in common I think you have to go down that hard road.